# Configuring single network interface in three different ways and setting routes based on certain conditions?

Tags: debian, networking, router

I have a [USB Armory Mk II](https://github.com/f-secure-foundry/usbarmory/wiki/Mk-II-Introduction) running Debian and it's fairly trivial to get up [the communication with the USB host](https://github.com/f-secure-foundry/usbarmory/wiki/Host-communication).

However, what I'd like to achieve is the following. I'd like to be able to configure the network adapter *on* the USB Armory conditionally. Three angles:

1. if DHCP is enabled on the host and binds to the [CDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_communications_device_class) Ethernet adapter, I want to use `dhclient` to assign it an IP.
2. the 10.0.0.0/24 network gets unconditionally (the one preconfigured on the Debian image provided by InversePath) configured on the interface with 10.0.0.1 assigned ...
3. configure 192.168.137.2 (or another 192.168.137.0/24 IP address other than .1) as yet another IP address ([Windows ICS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing))

Doing this is no big issue up to this point. As an example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12728345/476371) over on StackOverflow shows two ways of achieving it (I am going for the second one, adding the ICS range address as another alias).

But the crux is how the routes ought to be set. And that's the part where I am stuck right now:

1. if DHCP succeeded, I want to use whatever got configured through it as uplink (gateway)
2. if not, I want to check whether I can communicate on either of the remaining two configured subnets ... and preferably I'd like some piece of script on the USB Armory Mk II to figure out which gateway to use (i.e. try the obvious .1, .2 and .254 in the corresponding /24 subnet and then expanding the "search" if need be)

I need advice in the following areas:

- How to figure out best which of the IP ranges is viable as uplink? E.g. should I sniff ARP traffic and use that as an indicator? Or is there a more reliable method (e.g. `ping -I <address>`)? And as an afterthought: how to deal with changes in uplink availability?
- Instead of using some scripting, is there perhaps a reliable way of expressing this via [`ip-rule(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-rule.8.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've met a few of those scenarios in the past, but I still haven't found the perfect solution.

First, when you assign the two static IPs, make sure their routing metric is something high, like 1000. That way, if there is a DHCP default route, it will be lower and automatically chosen. This is the way I usually do it.

The next bit is far more tricky, because what is a good uplink? Linux will never make that choice for you - if a link is up, then it's up.

On the systems I work on with these issues, we always have a script or daemon running, and they can very quickly become very complex. We mostly test for connectivity against an endpoint at fixed intervals, and set routes accordingly, or set interfaces up or down.

We sometimes have preferred interfaces (e.g. Ethernet versus modem), in which case it becomes even harder, because we have to test if the Ethernet connection is running without breaking the modem connections.
I don't know if the ping -I switch work with interface aliases actually, but it might. If it doesn't, then you can also split the addresses entirely by using e.g. macvlan or ipvlan. This also enables setting an address (or its virtual interface) up or down.

Something entirely different, that we have to take into account, and you might also have to consider, is that we sometimes have to use different DNS servers, and maybe even restart services as well, when changing interfaces and subnets.

You'll find many guides to doing failover in linux, but they are almost always based on the physical link going down, which of course is easy to trigger on. Or they have a daemon, or script, which is what I'll suggest for testing routes.

Those was my 5 cents, I hope it makes some sense, and that it can lead you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. "Good" in this sense would be an uplink that works. I.e. that has IPv4 connectivity to the internet. Probably verified by attempting HTTP/HTTPS connections or so.